# react native fetch api value not updating after new state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I am trying to update my fetch, when new inputs come from this.state.values, but it does not work when using a textInput but re-renders when i manually place value in the this.state.values

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import LoadingScreen from './LoadingScreen';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { new: [], keyWord: '', loading: true, values:"GBP" };
    this.getCurrenceyInfo = this.getCurrenceyInfo.bind(this);
    this.getText = this.getText.bind(this);
  }

  getCurrenceyInfo(e) {
    this.setState({ keyWord: e });
  }

  getText(e) {
    this.setState({ values: e });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=11300ce6925109736ee5c&ids&interval=5m,30d&convert=${this.state.values}&per-page=100&page=1`
    )

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const ndata = data;
        const test = data.map((element) => element);
        this.setState({ new: test });
      });
  
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.new);
    const listItems = this.state.new.map((number) => (
      <Text>{number.price}</Text>
    ));

    return (
      <View>
    
        <TextInput onChangeText={this.getText} />
        <Text> {this.state.values}</Text>
        {listItems}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ideally i would like this.state.values to change its values from a textInput and update the fetch url, can someone help me and tell me where i am going wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called the API in [`componentWillMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) which is only triggered just before mounting occurs.
To reuse the fetch API, make it a method and call it where necessary.

Like this:

```
  getText(e) {
    this.setState({ values: e });
    this.fetchData();
  }

  // make api call a method
  fetchData() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=11300ce6925109736ee5c&ids&interval=5m,30d&convert=${this.state.values}&per-page=100&page=1`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const ndata = data;
        const test = data.map((element) => element);
        this.setState({ new: test });
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.new);
    const listItems = this.state.new.map((number) => (
      <Text>{number.price}</Text>
    ));

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={this.getText} value={this.state.values} />
        <Text> {this.state.values}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: hi Max this doesnt work. the api doesnt update as it should., It doesnt update the fetch

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I have made edits to the solution. your API call should be a method so you can access it elsewhere. Furthermore, if you want to display your response make use of a [`Flatlst`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist). Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot max! much appreciated and will now use flatlist